# How to surround numbers with double quotes in php preg_replace?

Tags: php, arrays, json, string, preg-replace

I have a json which seems to be invalid

```
{
        "systemId": 4424, 
        "professional":88928, 
        "gate":532, 
        "mock":02,
        "wish":"this", 
        "transaction_id":"eeases-323fasfse-asdfe33", 
        "channel": "API", 
    }
```

So hence, it cannot be converted to an array in php, i tried json lint and it shows an error at 02.

After some research I came to know that value starting from 0 in json is invalid.

When I surround 02 with double quotes "", than it was successfully converted to array using json_decode.

So I am wondering, how can I add quotes to number all assuming json to be a string.

Comment: You also have an extra comma at the end `"channel": "API", `.  So IMHO it would be better to try and fix the source rather than hack the results.

Comment: Try `$s = preg_replace('~":\s*\K0+(?=[1-9]\d*,)~', '', $s)`. A regex approach might not be safe though.

Comment: And you want to `preg_replace` this invalid value? Do you generate the JSON file? If so, I'd fix the code that generates the JSON instead

Comment: `02 with ["" was] successfully converted`, `how can I add quotes to [all numbers]` are you sure that gets you where you want?

Comment: Hi @greybeard , Yes I know "" around 02 is enough but I don't want the answer for the specific case, I was willing to learn something new.

Comment: @NigelRen I cannot fix the source, it is not in my hand I already spoke to them, they are not interested, hence trying to hack the string :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$data = '{
        "systemId":4424, 
        "professional":88928, 
        "gate":532, 
        "mock":02,
        "wish":"this", 
        "transaction_id":"eeases-323fasfse-asdfe33", 
        "channel": "API",
    }';


$data = str_replace('}', '', str_replace('{', '', $data));

echo '<pre>';


$t = preg_match_all("/(?<=\:)(.*?)(?=\,)/", $data, $matches);


$i=0;
foreach($matches[1] as $key => $value){
    if(is_numeric($value)){
        $matches[1][$i] = '"'.$value .'"';
    }
    $data = str_replace($value, $matches[1][$i], $data);
    $i++;
}

$data = rtrim(trim($data),','); //remove last comma


$data = '{'.$data .'}';

$data = json_decode($data,true);

print_r($data);
```

Dirty solution, and i agree 100% with the idea to "fix" your json before you get the response.

If you really really have to go that way to fix your json inside the code the above code will help you in that.

The reason i am trimming the curly brackets at first is to have a more clear string with the data. I concatenate them in the final format when i have done everything needs to be done.

The result of the code is :

```
Array
(
    [systemId] => 4424
    [professional] => 88928
    [gate] => 532
    [mock] => 02
    [wish] => this
    [transaction_id] => eeases-323fasfse-asdfe33
    [channel] => API
)
```

An array decoded from the valid json

Comment: Thank you so much for your efforts. Gonna try it 100%!

Comment: You're welcome i hope your problem gets solved. Let me know how did it go.

Comment: Hi @pr1nc3, I get {"systemId":" 4424", "professional":"88928", "gate":"532", "mock":"02", "wish":"this", "transaction_id":"eeases-323fasfse-asdfe33", "channel": "API",} before json_decode but nothing after json_decode

Comment: weird i use the exact same "json" you provided and works fine. Are you sure you did not modify any code cause i can still see the comma in the last field is there even though i trim it in my code. The last comma breaks your json and makes it invalid so can not be decoded to array. Make sure you did not remove my rtrim function.

Comment: Yes, the comma was the issue, Done! Thanks